# ArcMap Export Aspect Ratio

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, scale

I would like to change the aspect ratio of a map exported to image using ArcMap 10.8 or similar. For example, I would make the image of a country 20% wider without making it taller and without changing the legend dimensions.

Most options (changing the paper size in "page and print setup"; even with "scale map elements proportionally" checked; changing the dimensions of the layer) only change the dimensions of the extent, not the actual representation. I can't just rescale the whole image because that distorts the legend text.

*Note*: please do not respond that this is "bad" to do because of cartographic inaccuracy. In my use case, fitting the image properly is more important.